Writing a spec that involves Signal Trap and Process.kill - Only fails in CI?
I am struggling with writing specs for this implementation, which runs fine in my local env.
My theory is that since the spec has Process.kill instructions the github CI action job that runs this spec just gets terminated and fails. The logs are not very helpful, but I do see some terminated entries.
ruby 2.7.8
rails 7.0.8.4
module ProcessShutdownListener
  def initialize(...)
    setup_graceful_shutdown
    super
  end

  def shutdown_requested?
    @_shutdown_requested
  end

  private

  def setup_graceful_shutdown
    @_shutdown_requested = false
    Signal.trap("TERM") do
      graceful_shutdown
    end

    Signal.trap("INT") do
      graceful_shutdown
    end
  end

  def raise_error_on_process_shutdown?
    false
  end

  def graceful_shutdown
    @_shutdown_requested = true

    if raise_error_on_process_shutdown?
      raise ShutdownRequested
    end
  end
end

the spec:
class BasicExample
  include ProcessShutdownListener

  def raise_error_on_process_shutdown?
    false # default
  end
end

class AutomaticRaiseErrorExample
  include ProcessShutdownListener

  def raise_error_on_process_shutdown?
    true
  end
end

describe ProcessShutdownListener do

  describe "responding to process shutdown signals" do
    context "when #raise_error_on_process_shutdown? is false" do
      subject! { BasicExample.new }

      describe "#shutdown_requested?" do
        context "when process receives the TERM Signal" do
          it "returns true" do
            Process.kill("TERM", 0)
            expect(subject.shutdown_requested?).to be true
          end
        end

        context "when process receives the INT Signal" do
          it "returns true" do
            Process.kill("INT", 0)
            expect(subject.shutdown_requested?).to be true
          end
        end
      end
    end

    context "when #raise_error_on_process_shutdown? is true" do
      subject! { AutomaticRaiseErrorExample.new }

      context "when process receives the TERM Signal" do
        it "raises an error" do
          expect { Process.kill("TERM", Process.pid) }.to raise_error(ShutdownRequested)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Has anyone ever needed to write a similar spec around Signal Trap/Process.kill?

I'm not quite sure what's happening exactly here, but the way you are testing this does not seem right.
In particular:

In a unit test like this RSpec and your class are running in the same process, so there is always the potential to kill your test run somehow. Are you sure it is running fine on your local system and not just exiting silently? It is possible that CI is paying attention to that and you aren't. Check the $? shell variable after it runs.

According to the Ruby docs, killing PID 0 seems to kill the entire process group this process is in. I'm not up on all this, but killing other related processes might lead to your process getting killed. Did you mean to do this?

If you have other tests, these traps are globally configured, and what you have configured will not be torn down after the test completes, leaving the theoretical potential for intermittent test failures elsewhere due to run order and such. What happens during a test should not leave the test - but it's difficult to do in this case where you are dealing with process-level features.
This may not be an issue here because you seem to be setting up one set of traps per test, but you're playing with fire.
If you are familiar with rspec-mocks and such, which automatically clean up after themselves, you might be given the impression that you don't have to think about polluting other tests, but you do have to be wary of global effects like:

trapping
defining classes (i.e. global constants)
monkey patching them dynamically (except through singleton methods)
changing class variables (which can happen when you call class methods).


On a related note, you can only have one trap per signal, so making this a module does not make sense since if you do it once it will apply to the whole system and all of these tests, and any subsequent traps will overwrite the previous ones. The traps will not apply just to the one class. This logic would make more sense as a single service class.


If I were doing something like this, I would probably create a helper script using rails runner or something like that, which would run the trapping code in a different process.
You can't expect to receive an exception that occurs in a different process, but you can make sure your script outputs the exception, capture the output of the script in your test, and check the output is what you expect it to be.
You will probably also need to handle the no-exception case somehow, making sure it doesn't exit immediately before you've had a chance to send the signal, but still making sure it is killed before you are done:

You could do a small sleep in your script (say 5 seconds). It will need to be long enough to not make the test fail, and short enough to not hang around forever on your system.
Alternatively you could try an infinite loop somehow, perhaps doing sleep 1 or something in the loop to not kill your CPU. You need to do it in a way that the signal will get run properly.
If your script runs forever, you should ensure you clean up these processes - record the PID and forcefully kill the process (if it's still around) in an after block.

I'm not up on the exact semantics on whether and when sleep affects signal trapping, but there is some discussion at Is sleep() a good idea for the main loop of a job-scheduling app.
There may well be some gem that can make this easier, but I'm not familiar with one.

Thanks for the detailed reply and Idea @matthew.tuck!
